# free soul vs free spirit

Tags: american-english

I created a twitter account and put this in the bio:

> free soul, dreamer.. adventurer. forever young!

but someone told me that more correct it will be:

> free **spirit**, dreamer.. adventurer. forever young!

but he is not a native English speaker, so I need your advice.

Comment: If you want it to be even _more_ correct, try _Free spirit, dreamer, adventurer. Forever young._ Notice the correct punctuation (there is no such thing as `..`) and capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

The term "free spirit" is the more common usage, at least in North America.

"Old Soul" or "wise soul" are common descriptor for 'soul' when soul = person.

---

Personally, I think this is because 'spirit' is *analogous to* earthy + nature things.. which are "wild" and "free".  Whereas the 'soul' is a thing that is abstract from the confines of nature.... and therefore is *already free*.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion soul is referring to the person as a whole and spirit is referring to the person's attitude.  Free soul would have an odd meaning and free spirit is often used in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "free spirit, dreamer" is correct.